# How could I make my python code run faster?

Tags: python

I have a python code which saves the content of tables (1 column, second from the right) into an XLS file and does some editing on the content. I tested it in a folder with 38 files which in total has 22.000 lines and it took it 2.5hours to finish.

```
from docx import Document
from openpyxl import Workbook
import datetime

folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

for filename in os.listdir(folder):
    if filename.endswith(".docx"):
        doc = Document(os.path.join(folder, filename))
        for table in doc.tables:
            ws.append(["File name: " + filename])
            for row in table.rows:
                ws.append([row.cells[-2].text])

wb.save("output.xlsx")

for row in ws.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value and (cell.value[0] in ["+", "-", "="]):
            cell.value = "'" + cell.value

wb.save("output.xlsx")
```

Comment: rewrite it in [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/)

Comment: Try using pandas library to read and write the data from files instead of using docx and openpyxl. Use multiprocessing to process multiple files at once.

Comment: Is there any reason everything has to be done serially as opposed to concurrently? i.e. would it be an issue if you used a multiprocessing pool, one process for each file, and had their callbacks append to `ws`?

Comment: If your code runs without error and produces the correct result then you'll get better feedback on performance, style, technique if you repost your question over at the [Code Review StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).